# $\lambda$ values of $y''-(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\lambda}{x}).y=0$ such that there is a non trivial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

What are the $\lambda$ values such that $$\; y''-(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\lambda}{x}).y=0 \;;\; 0<x<\infty$$ $$ y(0)=0 \; ; \; \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}y(x)=0$$
have a non trivial solution.

Trying to use the Frobenius method, I found that $\; (s^2+s-\lambda).a_1=0\;$ and the recurrence relation $\; a_k=\frac{-1}{k.(k-1)}.(\frac{1}{4}.a_{k-2}+\lambda.a_{k-1})\;$. These results that I got are correct ? How can I get the answer by these results ?

One hint the professor gives is that $y(x)=\exp(-x/2).v(x)$.

Comment: If $v(x)$ is a solution, $v(0) = 0$ and $v(x)$ grows slower than $e^{x/2}$, then its Laplace transform $C s^{\lambda - 1} (s - 1)^{-\lambda - 1}$ is analytic on $\operatorname {Re} s > 1/2$.